# How do I use only file based dependencies in gradle instead of specifying groupId:artifactId:versionId

Tags: gradle, jar, jarjar

I have the following entry in my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.A:A:1.0'
}
```

which downloads  *'org.B:B:1.0'* because that's it's dependency.(not mentioned explicitly in gradle)

What I want to use in my project is A* and B* which are shadows(changed namespace) of A and B respectively.

Now, I have specified the dependency for A* as

```
dependencies{
    compile file('libs/A*.jar')
}
```

But, this one still downloads *'org.B:B:1.0'*

How do I wire the gradle to use **file('libs/B*.jar')**?

Comment: Why do you have the reference to the `A*.jar` twice in your project? Once as file dependency and once as maven dependency?

Comment: For A it's maven dependency, but for A* it's file dependency. Ultimately, I want only the file dependency.

Comment: So why don't you just remove the maven dependency?

Comment: I have removed it. The query is about getting B* instead of B which is being pulled in by A*.

Comment: File dependencies can't have transitive dependencies. So this: `compile file('libs/A*.jar')` can't pull any maven dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution that comes to mind is to exclude the transitive dependency of `compile 'org.A:A:1.0'`

This works like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.A:A:1.0') {
        exclude 'org.B:B:1.0'
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#N1532A) for more details on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, file dependencies can't have transitive dependencies. So `A*.jar` either has the contents of the `B.jar` rolled into it somehow, or you have `B.jar` on the build path somewhere else.

File dependencies are generally a tool of last resort, they do not participate in conflict resolution; you need a dependency repository like `maven` or `ivy` for that.